# creating hashmap in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, hashmap

I am creating a bean is spring as follows

```
<bean id="xyz" class ="java.util.HashMap">
  <constructor-arg  value ="${somehashMapPaceholder}"
</bean>
```

when i run this i get error as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personToDept' defined in class path resource [spring-configuration/application/appconfig-beans.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:250)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

I dont want to create hasmp using  due to some other reason.

Comment: can ${somehashMapPaceholder} only  point to String? or can it point some other hashmap ?  ${somehashMapPaceholder} is a referance to some other hashmap in my case

Comment: Could you give us a more complete example, especially where does `${somehashMapPaceholder}` come from and what is the contents? Why don't you use ref instead of value?

Comment: it somes from some there place there is some depedency that does it.But am not sure if ${somehashMapPaceholder}  can hold a reference to another map? Can a placeholder point to some other map?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings can u please help me with this

Comment: You can use `ref` attribute to refer to another bean in the context.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i dont create that bean.That it automatically availabe as i use some other lib.

Comment: There is no such thing as automatically available. Please show exactly what you mean.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my application works within a container which does some complex tasks. Now if i use such placeholder for string it works.But for ap  its not. i will try using <constructor-arg ref="{placholder} /> .

Answer (score 1):

you have to give the index number/name to the constructor args, while giving value for the constructor.
i.e like below

```
<bean id="test" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="Key 1" value="5" />
            <entry key="Key 2" value="6" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: i want to use constructort where u can pass another map to create a map. Eg mp = new HashMap(someothermap ) .So in spring someothermap is placeholder

Comment: Yes I tried with <bean id="test" class ="java.util.HashMap"><constructor-arg ref="test2"/></bean> <bean id="test2" class="java.util.HashMap"/> is working fine..let me try with placeholder will update you

Comment: Got the problem. placeholder was resolved as string and not object .

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap singleton can be implemented in the spring application context and shared across the IOC using the following util:map. First include xmlns:util in the schema.

```
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
```

Then define your shared map:

```
<util:map id="sendCounts"
    key-type="java.Lang.String"
    value-type="com.mycompany.ToFromCount"
    map-class="java.util.HashMap">
</util:map>
```

Then in your java source code:

```
    @Resource Map<String, ToFromCount> sendCounts;//needs to be in IOC for spring batch writer to use.
```

This sets up your hashmap key to be String, with the value being a class you define. If you wanted the value to be some other POJO or class from some other resource, just use that class as the value-type. The class which injects the map will then fill and access the map.

Using Spring STS in Eclipse, you can also set this up using the nice bean editor with your application context.xml file. See image below.
[image: Spring Bean Util Editor]

Hope this helps.